# How to create a multiLanguage site translating with JS

Tags: javascript, translation

I want to translate the text of every page using Javascript instead of PHP (because the PHP for the project I'm working is not very well designed, no framework, no templates etc).

I was thinking something like adding an attribute translate="yes" to every html to be translated, then get those nodes and search the text in some type of dict.
Pseudocode:

```
on window.load
$('[translate=yes]').each( el.text( translate( el.text() ) ) )
```

But I see two problems with this solution:
1) The visual glitch waiting the window.load event (will show original language). I could hide it with some preloader, but that could be even worst for the user experience.
2) Google won't index the translated page.

Is there a better way to do this in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Except for using already existing third-party translation solutions (like [Google's former translation widget](https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website/) which is no longer offered), I personally do not see a better approach.

I would suggest to not do this in frontend if it can be avoided. Apart from the reasons you already mentioned in your question, there are further problems like the need for loading or querying a (possibly rather large) dictionary in frontend each time a page is visited. This produces additional traffic and slows down the page which is likely to affect the UX in a negative way. In addition, this approach does not scale well, so if the page collection grows over time (when new pages are added), the performance will become even more bad.